# How to create multi-level list in Powerpoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

How can I create multi-level list in Powerpoint 2007?

I can't find Multi-Level List button on the Home tab as mentioned [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Microsoft-Office-Word-2007/0060__Style-Formatting/Formatthemultilevellist.htm).

Comment: What you referenced in the link was for MS Word 2007, not PowerPoint. Both answers below are correct - you may want to accept one of them.

Answer (score 1):

From [Introduction To Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007](http://www.cics.dept.shef.ac.uk/userguides/powerpoint2007.pdf):

> To create multi-level bulleted lists,
>   type in the text lines as usual. Click
>   at the start of any lines that you
>   wish to appear as a lower level list
>   then press the Tab key from the
>   keyboard. The selected lines will
>   receive an additional indent and will
>   get a different bullet symbol. Using
>   the Backspace key produces the
>   opposite effect.
>
> To change the bullet symbols used,
>   first click in one text line of the
>   list level that you wish to change.
>   Next, click the down arrow to the
>   right of the bulleted list button in
>   the Paragraph group on the Home tab.
>   Choose a bullet design from the
>   displayed collection.
>
> To choose a different button, click
>   the Bullets and Numbering option, then
>   in the dialog box that appears, click
>   the Customize button.

Comment: "The selected lines will ... get a different bullet symbol". I just tried, this does not work.

Comment: I tried it: It seems like the above never worked as it should. You therefore need to select/click the list line(s) and use Tab to demote or Shift-Tab to promote or use the corresponding icons in Home/Paragraph. Change the bullets via right-click/Bullets or the Bullets icon in Home/Paragraph.

Comment: @harrymc: this can be used as workaround, but I use numbered lists and it would be good to have correct numbering. And in case of bullets I need to change it for every promoted item :(

Comment: When demoting, numbering is done automatically: the demoted items start a new numbering and are taken out of the higher sequence. They can also inherit a new numbering/bulleting style from the Slide Master. If you want several preformatted styles, you'll need several Slide Masters.

Answer (score 0):

I see you asked this a while ago.  Not sure if you found an answer, but I just found a way to do it that might be helpful.  I'm sure more advanced users already thought of this, but I couldn't find it online...

What I did was I created a new slide master (you can find that on the view tab)... I copied the "title and content layout" slide master and changed it so instead of bullets each level had a different numbering scheme.  I renamed that slide master to "numbered title and content layout".  Then in the slide that I wanted the numbered list instead of the bullted list, I just applied my new slide master. Worked like a charm.  This way you don't have to change the numbering format each time you indent, the slide master took care of that for you.

Hope this helps, J